# OpenAI API: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401

Tags: javascript, typescript, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm trying to use OpenAI's API to generate recipes for a website, but
I keep getting the error in the title

code:

```
 const handleGenerateRecipe = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("https://api.openai.com/v1/completions", {
        prompt: `Generate a ${recipeType} recipe`,
        max_tokens: 60,
        n: 1,
        stop: "\n",
      }, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.API_KEY}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
      setRecipe(response.data.choices[0].text.trim());
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

I got the API key from my account, but I can't figure out why the API key is not working.

Tried regenerating my keys